# Android rss (rss 2.0 and atom ) parse error : line xxx column xxx:not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I am try a create my first Rss reader, but i have a problem.
i have a class, whose method return a feed list.

```
public ArrayList<FeedsItem> getFeedList()
        {
            final FeedsItem fi = new FeedsItem(Const.appDebugMode);
            final ArrayList<FeedsItem> fl = new ArrayList<FeedsItem>();
            /**
             * xml parse elements
             */
            RootElement root = new RootElement("rss");
            Element channel = root.getChild("channel");
            Element item = channel.getChild("item");


            item.setEndElementListener(new EndElementListener()
                {                       
                    @Override
                    public void end()
                        {
                            fl.add(fi.getCopy());                               
                        }
                });

            item.getChild("title").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener()
                {                       
                    @Override
                    public void end(String body)
                        {
                       fi.setTitle(body);                               
                        }
                });     

            item.getChild("link").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener()
                {                       
                    @Override
                    public void end(String body)
                        {
                            fi.setLink(body);                           
                        }
                });

            item.getChild("description").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener()
                {                       
                    @Override
                    public void end(String body)
                        {
                            fi.setDescr(body);                              
                        }
                });

            item.getChild("pubDate").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void end(String body)
                        {
                            fi.setPubDate(body);                                
                        }
                });

            item.getChild("guid").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener()
                {                       
                    @Override
                    public void end(String body)
                        {
                         fi.setGuid(body);                          
                        }
                });             
            /**             
             * парсим feed               
             */
            try
                {
                    Xml.parse(this.getInputStream(), Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    new FeedsParserWriteLog(Const.appDebugMode)
                     .WriteLog("FeedsParcer getFeed (parse xml) err= \n"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

            return fl;
        }
```

When I process the file format rss 2.0 - everything works (like this link http://news.yandex.ru/software.rss)
When I process the file format atom (like this link http://ithappens.ru/rss/)- i have a problem  **error : line xxx column xxx:not well-formed (invalid token)**

how i can process both formats? how do I rewrite the method to handle 2 formats?

thx

Comment: how i can check a charset?

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same problem as you, the issue in my case was that I was using `HttpURLConnection` and the response was **GZipped**.. it seems that the **urlConnection** doesn't unzip that for you so you have to do it yourself.

[Here](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2015/01/11/how-to-unzip-gzipped-inputstream/) you can find out how if you need to.

I hope it helps!